# "church's tradition" or "church tradition"

Tags: possessives, modifiers

> On Friday, three days before his resignation was made public, O'Brien told the BBC that celibacy should be reconsidered since it's not based on doctrine but rather **church tradition** and "is not of divine origin."
>
> [The Huffington Post](http://www.huffingtonpost.com/mobileweb/2013/02/25/pope-changes-conclave_n_2758053.html)

Had I written that piece, I would have written "church's tradition". So the question is: Why doesn't the journalist use the genitive "'s"?

Answer (score 5):

The possessive case is normally used when there is an animate "possessor" and in time expressions (*in a week's time*, for example).

Very often in English you create expressions in which you have two nouns used together, one of which serves as a kind of adjective, and as such is invariable.

So, in this sentence the writer has used the second structure, thus defining the noun *"tradition"* by connecting it to *"church"* used as an attribute. Personally, I feel that the genitive would not be suitable in this case.

Comment: Quite so. And with the genitive it would have to be *the Church's tradition*; doubtless somebody, either O'Brien or the journalist, was trying to avoid seeming to challenge the Church too explicitly, and to attribute the tradition to a vaguer generic churchly institutionality.

Answer (score 3):

The possessive is normally used when something *belongs* to somebody/something. *Church tradition* is using *church* as attribute of *tradition*: It describes *tradition*, in the same way *family* describes *business* in *family business*.

As for using the possessive with *church*, the *Corpus of Contemporary American English* has 2288 sentences containing "church's [noun]" where the noun following *church's* is, for example, one of the following:

- Position
- Response
- Money
- Choir
- Founder
- Future
- Pawn
- Effort
- Ministry

The sentences containing "church [noun] are 14032. In this case the noun following *church* is, for example, one of the following:

- Dogmatics
- Publications
- Magazines
- Strategy
- Officials
- Revivals
- Teaching
- Leaders
- Shoes

Notice that *church shoes* is different from *church's shoes*, and that *church hall* is generally used to mean a room or building associated with a church. (Sometimes *church hall* is used to mean *church*, the building where Christians go to worship.)